# Why the code below returns the same stuff?

Tags: php

```
var_dump(implode(',', array('11','22')));
```

And

```
var_dump(implode(array('11','22'), ','));
```

Which is right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [**the documentation on implode()**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php):

> implode() can, for historical reasons, accept its parameters in either order. For consistency with explode(), however, it may be less confusing to use the documented order of arguments.

The documented description is:

```
string implode ( string $glue , array $pieces  )
```

`implode(',', array('11','22'))` (the documented order) is identical to `implode(array('11','22'), ','))`. Both create the string `11,22`.

Answer (score 1):

Read this:

**implode() can, for historical reasons, accept its parameters in either order. For consistency with explode(), however, it may be less confusing to use the documented order of arguments.**

Taken from http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php

Both are accepted, but as it says above - documented order of arguments should be used.

Comment: The above quote should not be taken to mean that both are correct.